# Automatically Download File from a Webpage

Tags: php, download

Im trying to download a file that requires you to click "download" on the website.

```
https://apps.tdi.state.tx.us/sfsdatalookup/StartLookupAction.do?inquiryId=30
```

How do I write a php code to automatically download the file when I call the script?

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents("filename", fopen("https://apps.tdi.state.tx.us/sfsdatalookup/StartLookupAction.do?inquiryId=30", 'r'));
```

Comment: Warning: fopen(https://apps.tdi.state.tx.us/sfsdatalookup/StartLookupAction.do?inquiryId=30): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

Comment: You should probably enable this option in your php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to download the file with your script then the @Gudgip answer is correct but youe need check has the php.ini option `allow_url_fopen` set `true`

### download the file with curl

You can download files with curl extension (must be enable check you see `curl` when `$ php -m`)

```
$url = 'https://apps.tdi.state.tx.us/sfsdatalookup/StartLookupAction.do?inquiryId=30';

$temp_file = tempnam('/tmp', 'file_'); // return something like '/tmp/file_BQDfep'
$fp = fopen($temp_file, 'w+');

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// close the file
fclose($fp);

// now you have the file downloaded in '/tmp/file_BQDfep'
```

if you want when user click on that url then download a file from other URI try with

```
$file_url = 'http://remote.server.cim/file-to-download.exe';
$base_name = basename($file_url);

header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header(sprintf('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="%s"', $base_name)); 
readfile($file_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have headers and use read file like this.

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=yourfile.txt");
readfile("https://apps.tdi.state.tx.us/sfsdatalookup/StartLookupAction.do?inquiryId=30");
```